# Locking primitive for linked list

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, locking, semaphore

I saw few questions already on this topic, however I did not get the answer I wanted, hence asking this question again. In one of the interview, I was given a big linked list say million nodes. The operations on list will be search(read) and search + replace opertions(write). Question was which locking primitive will I prefer for these operations?

Being such a long list, I was obviously not choose spinlock as waiting threads will end up eating lot of CPU cycles. 
Also I could not go for per node mutex, as it is search and replace operation and will require all the locks in list to be gathered.
So I answered, read-write semaphore. Where write semaphores will have high priority to avoid priority inheritance issue. Also all reads can take place simultaneously.

I got rejected based on that answer :p. I am not very sure if my thoughts were correct about given question. Can someone please correct me if I am wrong in concepts?

Comment: Please add language tag

Comment: A readers/writers lock is close to what you described and is generally appropriate for such a situation. Though, it depends on what kind of replace operation you're talking about. If it's merely to replace the data of the nodes and does not require you to change any pointers, then you wouldn't need to lock any part of the list at all.

Comment: I would imagine, your interviewer wanted to see a lockless aproach?

Comment: As stated by @SergeyA , probably your interviewer wanted to see a lockless approach like RCU (Ready-Copy-Update). Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update and https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/whatisRCU.txt